Script properties not showing in inspector
I have a custom unit script. When i add it to a Game Object, the component properties doesn't show up.
Here's a screenshot of the Unity Editor:

I noticed that things show up correctly in Debug Mode:

And here is my code: https://pastebin.com/vBpAxtkL
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class CardPicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Variables
    [SerializeField] int test = 18;
    // Editor completed fields
    [SerializeField] List<Card> cardPool = new List<Card>();

    // Random
    private System.Random random = new System.Random();
    int totalWeight;
    #endregion

    #region Functions
    private void Awake()
    {
        ProcessTotalWeight();
    }

    private void ProcessTotalWeight()
    {
        totalWeight = 0;
        foreach (Card card in cardPool)
        {
            totalWeight += card.weight;
        }
    }

    private InventoryCard PickCard()
    {
        int roll = random.Next(totalWeight + 1);

        int sum = 0;
        foreach (var card in cardPool)
        {
            sum += card.weight;
            if (sum >= roll)
            {
                return new InventoryCard(card);
            }
        }
        return new InventoryCard(cardPool[0]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pick a specified amount of cards, adding them to the inventory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="amount">The amount of cards to pick</param>
    public List<InventoryCard> PickCards(int amount, List<InventoryCard> inventory)
    {
        List<InventoryCard> cards = new List<InventoryCard>();
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            InventoryCard card = PickCard();

            // Select the cards of the same type already present in the inventory
            var sameCards =
                from c in inventory.Concat(cards)
                where c.type == card.type
                select c;

            // If there is at least a card present, it's level is ugpraded
            int present = 0;
            foreach (InventoryCard c in sameCards)
            {
                present++;

                if (present >= card.maxAvailable)
                {
                    c.level += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Else the card is normally picked
            if (present < card.maxAvailable)
            {
                cards.Add(card);
            }
        }
        Debug.Log($"(CardPicker) Picked {cards.Count} cards");
        // Return the picked cards
        return cards;
    }
    #endregion
}

I use Unity 2022.3.20f1.
Can anybody help me with this ?

Yes they do :P Cardpicker has test and cardpool, its also showing other things because you have debug view on

Yes but when I disable Debug Mode properties dont show up anymore...

that would imply it hasnt compiled. as at leas those 2 would show
